# Infinite time in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, timespan

I'm trying to create a task which will repeat every 5 minutes indefinitely through powershell. However, I cannot figure out a way to do this through all my searching. `New-TimeSpan -Days 9999` appears to be the maximum value, and no matter what I do I cannot get the time to go over 9999 days.
Here's the trigger:
`$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $date -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 9999)  -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 5)`

`$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` reports what I assume to be v4, here's the output:
`Major  Minor  Build  Revision
4      0      -1     -1`

Comment: This is interesting. Usually when creating a scheduled task in the GUI, I would make it Daily, repeating every 5 minutes for a duration of 24 hours. But that combination is not possible with this cmdlet.

Comment: Here's infinity: `1.0/0` aww it has to be integer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `-RepetitionDuration ([timespan]::MaxValue)`

As of today, this gives you 10,675,199 days (almost 30,000 years).

See https://superuser.com/questions/403595/creating-a-scheduled-task-in-windows-that-will-run-at-intervals-indefinitely

Comment: It's not quite infinite, but I'd say 30,000 years is about sufficent. Definitely A lot better than just ~27 years. If someone figures out how to make it indefinite, I'll revise the answer chosen. Thanks! **EDIT** It turns out that windows interprets this as indefinite in the GUI. http://i.imgur.com/n1NZ3Qg.png

Comment: 200+ years is “infinite”.

Comment: Strangely enough, this actually seems to configure the schedule task correctly. If you export it to XML, you get the `<StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>` element. It must be some kind of undocumented sentinel value.

Comment: What do I do after 30,000 years?

Comment: This does not work anymore on recent systems. You now must remove the -RepetitionDuration option and your task will be re-executed by default infinite times.

Answer (score 2):

Omit `RepetitionDuration`:

```
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At '12:00am' -RepetitionInterval ([TimeSpan]::FromHours(2))
```

This runs at 12 AM and every 2 hours thereafter indefinitely.

#### Notes

This is per [@FireEmerald's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953897/infinite-time-in-powershell#comment115069419_29954088) on [the currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29954088/1958726), which doesn't work in PowerShell 7.2.5 on Server 2016.

The answer recommends setting `RepetitionDuration` to `[TimeSpan]::MaxValue`, which now errors out:

```
Register-ScheduledTask: The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range.
(8,42):Duration:P99999999DT23H59M59S
```